# wso2 api manager database

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I don't understand how can I access the data of APIs (api_id) USER (user_id), subscriptions (is a user 'x' subscribed to API 'y'?) ...

**how can I perform such controls by connecting to some db?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your question is not much clear,hope you want to know how WSO2 API Manager implemented database data accessing part.I'll explain how WSO2 API Manager did controlling over database data.

You could found the database scripts[it contains h2/mysql/oracle dbscripts] use by WSO2 API Manager from [1] which used to create the database table structure of it.You'll notice there are separate database tables to store information on APIs[AM_API] ,subscribers[AM_SUBSCRIBER] and subscriptions[AM_SUBSCRIPTION],etc.And  you'll notice how foreign keys have been used to enable relationships among tables to perform controls over data while ensuring that the data stored in a consistent way.

Then there's an inbuilt java API defined for WSO2 API Manager related back-end functionalities and you can found it from [2] and its implemented java code can be found from [3].If you have a look on ApiMgtDAO.java class implementation in org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl bundle,you'll get a better understanding how the database access layer for API Manager implemented with querying through database data.

Hope above will help to you.

Thanks;

/Lalaji

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/products/apimgt/1.0.0/modules/distribution/resources/sql/

[2]https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api/1.0.0/

[3]https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/1.0.0/

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for the answer, second: how do I download all the package? for example if I want to call "getAccessKeyForAPI" of the ApiMgtDAO.java, do I have to import all the package org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao...sorry but I am not really an expert of java

Comment: my goal is to control API usage: I need to limit the usage to 20 calls of each user, but I could not do that with throttling tiers.

Comment: Hi, If you want to modify the coode and use,first you need to download the source code and compile and build it with maven.You can download the WSO2 API Manager related full source code from http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/ by navigating to Downoad->Source option. And follow the steps in the README file inside that.

Comment: Answering to your second question,in WSO2 APIManager,there are few pre-defined throttling tier levels as 'Gold,Silver,Bronze,Unlimited'.From these tiers, 'Gold' means allow a user to throttle 20 requests per unit time[per min].But note you could change these throttling tiers configurations as well.The following blogpost will hlp you on how to do that.http://sumedha.blogspot.fr/2012/06/how-to-add-new-throttling-tier-to-wso2.html

Comment: How to connect to the WSO2 database though client ?