# wso2 carbon database table definitions

Tags: wso2

I can see a bunch of scripts in the $CARBON_HOME/dbscripts folder, but would like some more information about the schema.

Is there any documentation that describes all the tables that are created by carbon?

Here are the tables used by Carbon 4.0.1.  It looks like there are two major types of data being managed: Registry (REG_x) and User Management (UM_x).

```
REG_CLUSTER_LOCK
REG_LOG
REG_PATH
REG_CONTENT
REG_CONTENT_HISTORY
REG_RESOURCE
REG_RESOURCE_HISTORY
REG_COMMENT
REG_RESOURCE_COMMENT
REG_RATING
REG_RESOURCE_RATING
REG_TAG
REG_RESOURCE_TAG
REG_PROPERTY
REG_RESOURCE_PROPERTY
REG_ASSOCIATION
REG_SNAPSHOT

UM_TENANT
UM_USER
UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE
UM_ROLE
UM_PERMISSION
UM_ROLE_PERMISSION
UM_USER_PERMISSION
UM_USER_ROLE
UM_DIALECT
UM_CLAIM
UM_PROFILE_CONFIG
UM_CLAIM_BEHAVIOR
UM_HYBRID_ROLE
UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE
UM_HYBRID_REMEMBER_ME
```

Comment: The easiest way is to send them an email asking them for this info. I've not seen a doc that details these internal tables. They are subject to change obviously. Out of curiosity is there a reason you want to read these ?

Comment: Thanks for the response Deepak. I'm just trying to get a deeper understanding of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the database table definitions of WSO2 Identity Server in [1]. Most of the tables are common to other products as well.

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2015/04/wso2-identity-server-data-dictionary.html

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer I have found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251336/wso2-api-manager-database?rq=1)

I guess I will need to look through the DAO's and try and work out what is happening from there.